# How should I build this app over communcation apps?

Tags: web, architecture

These days I am finding myself in the position of having to implement for one of my college courses a system that should act as a giant wrapper over many communications apps like Gmail , Facebook Messenger maybe even WhatsApp .To put it simply you should have a giant web interface where you can authorize Gmail , Messenger and use them at once when required. I am thinking of going with an REST API to manage the user's services authorized by OAuth2.Also I am thinking of using Node.JS and Express.js in the backend and React.js in the frontend. I found some sweet libraries in npm that should take care of interacting with the involved APIs(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gmail-api this one for instance), but I am also doubtful about this approach , for example I have no idea how to keep the use notified about its incoming mails or messages for example . I am in dire need of some expertise since I forgot to mention but I am quite the newbie in this field. To sum it up for once my question is how would you implement such an infrastructure ? Is it my approach viable or I am bound to hit some really hard to overcome obstacles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a college exercise, it would be a really fun experiment, so it definitely worth the time you want to put into it. However, once you want to add more features, the complexity will go up pretty fast.

Here are a couple of ideas you can think of:

- It's pretty clear that your system can't do more things than the capabilities exposed by the APIs of communication apps (e.g. you can't have notifications in gmail if the API doesn't have this capability).
- For that reason, you should carefully study the APIs and what functionalities they expose. They have public docs that you can check out: ([Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest), [Facebook Messanger API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/))
- Some of the apps you want to communicate with may not have an official API (e.g. WhatsApp) - those kinds of details you definitely want to know from the start.
- Based on the analysis of those APIs, you should lay out a list of requirements for your system, which can be extracted from all the APIs, for example: message notifications, file transfers, user profiles, etc.
- In this way, you know exactly what capabilities your system should have, and you don't end up implementing a feature that is available only in 1 API out of 4.
- Also, it would be a bit challenging to design your system from a user perspective, because the apps have different usage patterns - chat apps, where messages are coming in real-time, vs email, which is not real-time communication. That's just a detail anyway, the gist of your project is to play with those APIs.

Also, it may worth checking out the [Gateway Aggergation Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/gateway-aggregation), which is related to this project - you may want the user to send a message to multiple apps, by using a single request to your service.